# Javascript Timer click button every 0.1 seconds

Tags: javascript

I have a timer ( 15 ) and it count down till it reach 0 and then it repeat

their is a button that I want to click when the timer is less than 2 
 my code is :

```
    setInterval(function(){
var x = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML ;
function getSecondPart(str) {
    return str.split('00<span>:</span>00<span>:</span>')[1];
}
    if (getSecondPart(x) < 04) {
       document.getElementById('bidButton').click();

    }

  } ,100);
```

but is return this error :

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','
```

why ?

Comment: I think your missing a curly brace before `,100);`

Comment: Wait... you changed the code. Are you saying that you still get the same error even after fixing the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a bracket to close the function:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if (getSecondPart(x) < 2) {
       document.getElementById('bidButton').click();
    }
} ,100);
```

Try to use more indentation and it will be clearer.

Comment: should I call it to make it working ? setInterval();

Comment: @LineRifai The code above is the calling. It invokes the `setInterval` method with two parameters: the function to run, and the interval itself.

Comment: thanks so much bro , worked perfect